# Sql update column with time from

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update `customdate1` column with the time from `starttime` column. The issue I'm having is formatting. The current format for `starttime` is HH:MM:SS.SSSSSSS I need it to be in HH:MM.

[image]

Thank you
Brian

Comment: The DateTime datatype does NOT have a format. It stores the data consistently. If you only want HH:MM in the front end you should put that formatting in the front end.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add formatting functions to your select queries.  I suggest dropping the 4 custom fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you first change your data type and then perform an update

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ALTER COLUMN CustomDate1 time(0) not null


UPDATE tablename
SET customdate1 = (SELECT starttime) 
                   FROM tablename);
```

If you don't want to store seconds you can change your data type to char(5) and then perform an update. But this is not recommended . Any formatting should be done at the application level

See example:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ALTER COLUMN CustomDate1 char(5) not null


UPDATE tablename
SET customdate1 = (SELECT starttime) 
                   FROM tablename);
```

See a quick example:

```
DECLARE @time char(5) = '12:15';
SELECT @time AS '@time'
```

Comment: @Brian why do you bother seconds? At the application level it can be formatted without them.

Comment: Im trying to create a dimension for a cube in MS visual studio. every time I attach the time measure to it I get the error... Errors in the back-end database access module. The size specified for a binding was too small, resulting in one or more column values being truncated.

Comment: When I look at another dimension, that works, the data it pulls from the SQL table is formatted HH;SS

Comment: @Brian http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072150/ssas-cube-processing-error-about-column-binding

Comment: I was able to get it to process with the HH:MM Char(5). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET customdate1 = (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, starttime, 108), 1, 5) 
                   FROM tablename);
```

Try above one. Date will be truncated to 5 characters. `hh:mm`

Comment: This doesn't change the default "appearance" of the value, it will however update the value to make the values all 00 after the minutes.

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0):

The date will be stored in the format the column was created e.g. datetime

You will need to convert the date into the format you need when retrieving the date from the table e.g. `CONVERT(CHAR(5), customdate1, 108)`

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype you are using ? if it is time you can change the fractionnal seconds precision by setting the column datatype to time(0)

Comment: starttime is a time(7) and customdate1 is a datetime

Comment: if you can't change starttime datatype to time(0) try using convert(varchar, StartTime, 8)

Comment: I got customdate1 set to time(0), still show up as HH:MM:SS

Comment: try using convert(varchar(5), StartTime, 8) in the update statement

Comment: I should also add that the minimal size for a time column is 8 characters so unless you convert its dataType to varchar which is not recommended as @dejan87 mentionned you can't get rid of the seconds part

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to select a `DATETIME` type column as a wanted format, but you can create a `VIEW` which has selected columns as well as another column for `HH:MM` format.

So you can use in the select list of the `VIEW` something like this:

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, ..., CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)  AS CustomDate1_Formatted
```